# logstash forwarder error in elk

Tags: logstash

```
[root@sys2 logstash-forwarder]# rpm -qa | grep -i logstash logstash-forwarder-0.4.0-1.x86_64
```

I do get this error

```
2015/09/26 14:37:03.434672 Failed to tls handshake with 192.168.1.235 read tcp 192.168.1.235:5001: i/o timeout
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved thanks to google. I googled and found that upgrading elasticsearch to the latest version alleviates the issue. I also increased the logstash-forwarder timeout to 5 minutes(from 15 seconds). I now have three logstash forwarders supplying logs to the logstash server. I am however keeping my fingers crossed.
I followed this post:
https://github.com/elastic/logstash-forwarder/issues/360

Answer (score 0):

An i/o timeout, aside from the usual networking issues, can also be a sign of a logstash that's overloaded.  Tune logstash (may guides to that on the web), and you can also try decreasing the batch size and increasing the timeout in logstash-forwarder.

Comment: Thanks for taking an interest in my issue. I only have two systems sending logs to the logstash server. Very few logs, /var/log/messages and /var/log/secure. The logstash server is a quad core i5 with 8GB of RAM. I'll try increasing the timeout and report back.

Comment: increased timeout to 60. Still getting this: 2015/09/27 13:23:27.162118 Failed to tls handshake with 192.168.1.235 read tcp 192.168.1.235:5001: i/o timeout. On the logstash server: load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.05
[root@elk certs]# free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7711         970        6279          57         461        6432
Swap:          7951           0        7951

Comment: Can you telnet/nc from the shipping host to the receiving host on the desired port?